# PHP - function associated with str_replace only run when needed

Tags: php, templates, replace, str-replace

I was using the str_replace() function to replace some contents within a text file. My code:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('script.txt');
function makefile() {
   $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
   fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
   fclose($file);
   return "Done!";
}
$templates = array("{{time}}", "{{PI}}", "{{make}}");
$applied = array(date("h:i:sa"), 22/7, makefile());
$str = str_replace($templates, $applied , $txt);
echo $str;
```

The script.txt contains:

```
The time is {{time}}  <br>
The value of PI is {{PI}}
```

As you can see, it's just a simple templating system. the makefile() function is used only for testing purpose. The script.txt file has no {{make}} templates. So normally, the makefile function won't need to be called during replacement operation. But when I run the code, it creates the test.txt. Which mean makefile() runs. Is there any way to avoid this kind of unnecessary function operations? And run them only when needed?

Comment: Since makefile is what creates the file, it will create the file soon as the function runs. There is no way around that. Even if you looped through and did each replace separately, only calling makefile when doing the replacement, it won't return `Done!` before writing the file so the `{{make}}` won't get replaced. That is probably the closest you would get without just calling the function to create the file at the end. PHP doesn't have any sort of setTimeout to delay the execution of the code that creates the file to asynchronously continue makefile and write sometime after it is done.

Comment: You would just have to move the logic to write to file down below and not use str_replace for the `{{make}}` replacement. Remove `{{make}}` and the corresponding `makefile` from the arrays in str_replace and then below check `if(strpos($txt, '{{make}}') !== false){ makefile(); }` so you call makefile at the end if `{{make}}` exists in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add `strpos` check.  `strpos` in php is used to find the position a substring occurs in a string, but if the substring never occurs, then it will return false.  Leveraging that, we can do:

```
<?php

$txt = "The time is {{time}}  <br>
The value of PI is {{PI}}";
function makefile() {
   $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
   fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
   fclose($file);
   return "Done!";
}
$templates = array("{{time}}", "{{PI}}", "{{make}}");
$applied = array(date("h:i:sa"), 22/7, strpos($txt,"{{make}}") ? makefile() : false);
$str = str_replace($templates, $applied , $txt);
echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Though it's an indirect way I hope it'll help.

Comment: Updated code: added an inline if statement, that should make it more concise.

Comment: Even more better!